# Can you split an MVC Area across two projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an Asp.Net MVC 3 website written in VB.Net. We want to migrate to C#, the plan being to write all new code in C#, and rewriting old code as and when it's amended.

I created a new C# MVC 3 project in the solution. Within this project I am using Razor Generator to help compile the views into the resulting assembly. I reference the C# project from the VB one. The VB project runs as the main site.

This set up works 90% beautifully. However, if an Area already exists in the VB project, I can't seem to extend it in the C# project. It appears that the whole Area has to exist in either one project or the other.

Does anyone know if it is possible to serve 1 area from 2 projects?

Answer (score 0):

I had to work around this by creating a route in the area registration of the VB.Net project.

The Area Registration file in the C# project needed to be removed, and the route in the VB.Net project uses a slightly different URL pattern. When creating the new route the Namespace that the C# controllers reside in need to be set. The new route also needs to be declared before the default route for the area.

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible, and what you are doing is correct. I would surmise that your routes are not set up correctly. You will have to specify the namespaces in the routing in your VB project.

In your AreaRegistration code:

```
Public Overrides Sub RegisterArea(ByVal context As AreaRegistrationContext)
    context.MapRoute(
        "Users_default",
        "Users/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        New With {.action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional},
        New String() {"MyCompany.MyAmazingCSProject.Areas.Users.Controllers", 
                      Me.GetType().Namespace}
    )
End Sub
```

**Remember** that VB namespaces have the added complication of root namespaces, which work differently to the Default namespace of C# projects, so if you're working with both, you need to be consistent.

**i.e.**
A VB project with a root namespace of `MyCompany.MyAmazingVBProject` has this namespace in code:

```
Namespace Areas.Users.Controllers
```

which maps to `MyCompany.MyAmazingVBProject.Areas.Users.Controllers`, whereas the equivalent namespace in C# would have this code:

```
namespace MyCompany.MyAmazingCSProject.Areas.Users.Controllers { ... }
```